# Visual Studio Code Python Debugger Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code

I seem to be missing something simple, but I can't figure out why I am unable to debug python using Visual Studio Code on Windows. I've tried setting up the debugger as shown by [Microsoft](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging), and this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNFgRUD2w68). I've done a clean install of Visual Studio Code (including the python extension) and Python 3.6. I have no other python versions installed. I keep getting the following errors in the Python Debugger:

```
cd "c:\Users\xxx\Documents\Python Scripts" ; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" "C:\Users\xxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.3.1\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_launcher.py" "c:\Users\xxx\Documents\Python Scripts" 53746 34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14 RedirectOutput,RedirectOutput "c:\Users\xxx\Documents\Python Scripts\.vscode\launch.json"
    -bash: cd: c:\Users\xxx\Documents\Python Scripts: No such file or directory
    env: ‘C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\python.exe’: No such file or directory
```

It's complaining that it can't find the python.exe file, but it clearly can since VS code indicates that it's attached:

[image: VS Code Python Attached]

My launch.json file is the default, and I've tried all the configurations:

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "port": 3000,
            "secret": "my_secret",
            "host": "localhost"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Terminal (integrated)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Terminal (external)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput",
                "Django"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask (0.11.x or later)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceFolder}/app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "module.name"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Pyramid",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/development.ini"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput",
                "Pyramid"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Watson",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/console.py",
            "args": [
                "dev",
                "runserver",
                "--noreload=True"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: All debug Options",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "module": "module.name",
            "env": {
                "VAR1": "1",
                "VAR2": "2"
            },
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "args": [
                "arg1",
                "arg2"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Pylinting works fine, and I have not custom user settings in Visual Studio Code that are related to python. I've tried setting the complete file path to python.exe in settings.json but it makes no difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem but finally got out of it after several adjustment to my settings.
make sure all other settings are in place as you've mentioned especially **pythonPath** in settings.json and also get "python" installed from the "extension" toolbar in VS code.
Simply change your debug configuration from *"Python: Scripts"* (or any other configuration you've selected previously) to *"Python: Terminal(external)"* and you are good to go!

Comment: Such a minor change to my setup but it finally worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know, is a pain and I'm experiencing the same.

Apparently `python.exe` is executing correctly. You will keep seeing that banner because "This is necessary to bootstrap the debugger."

At least this is what Microsoft [says](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1880).